# Connect Web Service in Java with SOAP Client Objective C without WSDL2OBJC and Sudz C?

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, web-services, soap-client

I have this web service in Java:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "Catalogo_V1")
public class Catalogo_V1 {

    /** This is a sample web service operation */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) 
    {
        System.out.println("kkk"+txt);
        if(txt != null)
        {
            txt= txt +"www";
        }

        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }

}
```

I have tryed with WSDL2OBJ and dont send my parameters, finally i have decided change and probe with other tecnology.

Can someone help me???

Comment: Sorry, I do not get your question. What exactly did you try and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: My problem is that after generate code, program my client in objective c and run my service... its impossible send any parameters, for example, if i want show " Hello David!! " and David is my parameter i only dont send this and show "Hello null!".....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for an alternative to something like SudzC, you can always work with simple SOAP interfaces by hand. It's really not that hard to do, but it does require you to generate the outgoing XML and parse the incoming XML yourself.

When I've done this, I've managed it by creating "template" versions of my requests and bundled them with my iOS app. When I need to make a request I pull in the template XML file and do some simple string/XML manipulation to insert the parameters into the request XML. Then I submit the XML request, get the XML response, and parse out the parts of the response I care about.

This is not something I would recommend if you are doing lots of different SOAP calls with complex XML inputs or outputs. But for simple SOAP requests, it works just fine.

Comment: This is the problem i need send a lot of data in my comunications, similar to 200 images encoded in Base64. I think that i,d lose a lot of time modifing XML files.

Comment: This is exactly what I've done for a small/medium SOAP API, right down to bundling the request 'templates' in the app. Generally, create an asynchronous request object with a delegate for each distinct SOAP call, worked pretty well for me.

Comment: Really?? I need something similar to this, could i use your API?

Comment: I have follow your comment and have created a manual request but the problem is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280851/objective-c-soap-request-with-java-web-service